# Time and date picker android

Tags: android, datetime, time

I am working on android application in which i want to select date and time. I am using the following methods in which i am getting the time on dialog. But i want to do something like that when i click for time dialog it will also show me date. Please help me out here:

```
private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener timePickerListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {


            @Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minutes) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                hour   = hourOfDay;
                minute = minutes;

                updateTime(hour,minute);

             }

        };

        private static String utilTime(int value) {

            if (value < 10)
                return "0" + String.valueOf(value);
            else
                return String.valueOf(value);
        }
    // Used to convert 24hr format to 12hr format with AM/PM values
    private void updateTime(int hours, int mins) {

        String timeSet = "";
        if (hours > 12) {
            hours -= 12;
            timeSet = "PM";
        } else if (hours == 0) {
            hours += 12;
            timeSet = "AM";
        } else if (hours == 12)
            timeSet = "PM";
        else
            timeSet = "AM";


        String minutes = "";
        if (mins < 10)
            minutes = "0" + mins;
        else
            minutes = String.valueOf(mins);

        // Append in a StringBuilder
         String aTime = new StringBuilder().append(hours).append(':')
                .append(minutes).append(" ").append(timeSet).toString();

          txtTimePicker.setText(aTime);
    }
 @Override
        protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
            switch (id) {
            case TIME_DIALOG_ID:

                // set time picker as current time
                return new TimePickerDialog(this, timePickerListener, hour, minute,
                        false);

            }
            return null;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put the following code according to your requirement:

```
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 

        try {
            dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
         SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy"); 

         String newDateStr = postFormater.format(dateObj); 

         txtTimePicker.setText(newDateStr+" "+aTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want both a time picker and a date picker, there are two different dialog classes you need to use: [TimePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.html) and [DatePickerDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DatePickerDialog.html).

So if you want the user to pick a date too, you need to show a DatePickerDialog before or after you show the time picker one. You can show a DatePickerDialog the same way you showed your TimePickerDialog.

Comment: @Alexandra Rosianu thanks for your reply. Yes i want the it to be on the same way as you described.